# mysql view to reinsert data

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates, view

I am building database for some BI tools.

Data that in my database

```
id   date      name
1    1/8/2017  John
2    1/8/2017  Bob
3    2/8/2017  Alice
4    3/8/2017  Daisy
```

I would like to create a view become

```
id   date      name
1    1/8/2017  John
2    1/8/2017  Bob
1    2/8/2017  John
2    2/8/2017  Bob
3    2/8/2017  Alice
1    3/8/2017  John
2    3/8/2017  Bob
3    3/8/2017  Alice
4    3/8/2017  Daisy
```

I just want the date to be duplicate/reinsert every day, I know this will create many redundant data but due to some limitation on BI tools, this is the format I needed.

Currently I create a new table with exact structure, then write a cron job to populate the data into new table everyday. I wonder views can done something like this?

Answer (score 0):

YES,you can Update and Insert into view and that edit will be reflected on the original table

Few things you need to take care of

1. The view should have all the NOT NULL values on the table.
2. The update should have the same rules as table

   As far as my understating you can create a Trigger or a Stored Proc to be called from A CRON JOB  if you want to achieve above functionality..

Comment: I dont want to reflect on the original table, and canm you eleaborate more?